# Decrease Date On Change of Year

Tags: c#, winforms, datepicker

I am using two **DatePicker** in a `WinForm` and trying to do a simple thing. Whenever I try to select date, say **Start Date**, then **End Date** should be decreased by a year. but there is a condition. Example, if the **Start Date**
is '10-12-2018', then **End Date** should be '10-12-2017'. In the same way, if **Start Date** is '10-12-2017', then **End Date** will be '10-12-2016'. Again, if **Start Date** is '10-14-2017', then **End Date** will be '10-12-2016'. Because the day is changed, not the year.

I've tried with the vice-versa means increasing the year with **DatePicker** value changed event and was close enough with
the following:

```
public frmDetails()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   dtPickerEnd.Value = dtPickerEnd.Value.AddYears(1); //By default adding one year for end date
}
```

When changing the start date:

```
private void dtPickerStart_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (dtPickerStart.Value.Year == dtPickerEnd.Value.Year) //If year is same, then increase year by one
   {
      dtPickerEnd.Value = dtPickerEnd.Value.AddYears(1);
   }
}
```

It works when I increase the start date, but doesn't work when I do the reverse. Like if **Start Date** is '10-12-2018', then **End Date** supposed to be '10-12-2019'. Same way, if **Start Date** is '10-12-2017', then **End Date** be '10-12-2018'. But now I am willing to stick with the decreasing year. Unfortunately, I am not getting the expected result with this:

```
private void dtPickerStart_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (dtPickerStart.Value.Year == dtPickerEnd.Value.Year) //If year is same, then increase year by one
   {
      dtPickerEnd.Value = dtPickerEnd.Value.AddYears(-1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public frmDetails()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    oldStartYear = dtPickerStart.Value.Year;
    dtPickerEnd.Value = dtPickerStart.Value.AddYears(1); // or -1
}

private int oldStartYear;

private void dtPickerStart_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (oldStartYear != dtPickerStart.Value.Year)
    {
        oldStartYear = dtPickerStart.Value.Year;
        dtPickerEnd.Value = dtPickerStart.Value.AddYears(1); // or -1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

i have tried and it worked

```
    try
    {
    dateTimePicker2.Value = new DateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value.Year - 1, dateTimePicker1.Value.Month, dateTimePicker1.Value.Day);
    }
    catch
    {
     if(dateTimePicker1.Value.Month==2 && dateTimePicker1.Value.Day==29)
     {
       dateTimePicker2.Value = new DateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value.Year - 1, dateTimePicker1.Value.Month, dateTimePicker1.Value.Day-1);
     }
  }
```

Comment: It won't solve the problem and even crash when dateTimePicker1.Value = 2016-02-29.

Comment: its because 29 feb only exists in every 4 year put the code inside the try catch block or handle when user picks 29 Feb go for 28 feb or 1 march its on you